# TinyMCE: Plug-In for applying multiple classes to a textblock

Tags: css, class, plugins, tinymce, styling

The question whether it is possible to apply multiple classes/styles to an element in TinyMCE has already been asked and properly answered.

However, i wanted to ask around whether anyone has found any prepared plugin for this purpose, or perhaps has even written his own?

Certainly i am also open for alternative approaches, should someone know of any!

Thank You!

Comment: "The question whether it is possible to apply multiple classes/styles to an element in TinyMCE has already been asked and properly answered."  Has it?  If so, I'd love to know where this proper answer is!  I can't find any way to do it and this question is ranking high in Google's page rank for trying to find a way to add multiple classes to an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a plugin, this functionality is built in to TinyMCE:

- http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:formats
- http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:style_formats

Example:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    style_formats : [
        {title : 'Error Message', classes : 'message error'},
        {title : 'Headline', classes : 'heading heading-loud page-heading'}
    ]
});
```

This creates two options under the `styleselect` control, labeled by `title`, which will apply all the `classes` to the element.

There's quite a bit more you can do with this, make sure to read the docs thoroughly.

Comment: this is perfect. thank you for bringing my attention to where it belongs :)